# Are there B2 alpine boot brands in the UK besides La Sportiva and Scarpa?

Tags: boots, uk, alpine, b2-boots

I'm looking at buying some B2 rated alpine/winter boots for use with Crampons, etc. I'm trying to avoid paying full price for them (searching ebay, looking for special offers, etc.) as they are prohibitively expensive (£300+).

In the main UK sites selling this kind of stuff only seem to offer two brands, **La Sportiva** and **Scarpa**. I was under the impression that these were the only brands that made these kinds of boots (I did see one pair of now discontinued **North Face** boots) when someone pointed out that **Meindl** also make these types of boot. I've never seen a UK shop selling these.

So what *other* brands make B2 rated alpine/winter boots? Which one's am I missing. If I can build up a list of brands it will hopefully make my bargain shopping easier.

Comment: Koflach is a popular and cost effective choice, standard double plastic boot.

Comment: I'm not really after a double plastic boot @AM_Hawk . I want a solid construction one. Sorry, didn't specify this. I'll have a look at that brand too though!

Comment: I personally am a LaSportiva whore, OlyMons, EVO's, Miura's, Solutions and Katana's.  I seek out the big discounts, they're out there, you just need to find them.  Good Luck!

Comment: I just familiarized myself with the "B" Rating System, sorry.

Comment: @AM_Hawk La Sportiva's are lovely. I think the issue is there is limited demand for them in this country so they're a specialist item so yiu don't get many discounts. Oh well back to hunting! thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have a very limited range of brands over on your island *

Beside the brands you already mentioned here are some others that spring to mind:

- [Hanwag](http://www.hanwag.com/products/outdoor/alpin)
- [Lowa](http://www.lowa.de/en/products/outdoor/alpine.html)
- [Mammut](http://www.mammut.ch/en/products_footwear.html)
- [Salewa](http://www.salewa.us/footwear/mountaineering)
- [Dachstein](http://www.dachsteinschuhe.com/en/produkte/mountaineering)

---

- I know, you're the continent, we're the island ;-) !

Comment: Yeah it seems to be an issue. I think it's because we don't have any alps?! :)

Comment: yeah, you should definitely get some alps, they're great! ;-)

Comment: We do have [wild haggis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_haggis) though

Comment: Oh nice, looks like they have a close relative living here in southern germany. We call them [Wolpertinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolpertinger)

Comment: ha ha, awesome!